# Python-Quickbooks Invoice object not updating tax code

Tags: python, api, quickbooks

I am using the Python-QuickBooks library and after selecting a tax code and an invoice to put it on, once I save the invoice does not save the tax code reference however it saves everything else.

Here is the code:

```py
with open("refresh.txt", "r") as f:
    refresh = f.readline()

ac = AuthClient(
    client_id='CLIENTID',
    client_secret='CLIENT_SECRET',
    redirect_uri='https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl',
    environment=Environments.PRODUCTION
)

try:
    client = QuickBooks(
        refresh_token=refresh,
        auth_client=ac,
        company_id='123456'
    )
    print("Successfully made client")
except AuthClientError as ace:
    print("Invalid refresh token!")
    print(ace)
    quit()

tax_service = TaxCode.filter(Name="Shannon County Tax Rate", qb=client)[0]
tsr = tax_service.to_ref()
invoice = Invoice.filter(DocNumber='5449W', qb=client)[0]

for line in invoice.Line:
    if isinstance(line, SalesItemLine):
        line.SalesItemLineDetail.TaxCodeRef.value = "TAX"

invoice.TxnTaxDetail.TxnTaxCodeRef = tsr

invoice.save(qb=client)

with open("refresh.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(client.refresh_token)
```

And after running the code again it shows that the invoice tax code hasn't changed, and it also shows it hasn't updated on the website and still only shows the "Based on Location" Tax rate

[Image of tax rate location in Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE0EI.png)

The expectation being that it is set to the "Shannon County" tax code that already has a defined percent for tax rate.

I've also looked into the TaxService object in quickbooks.objects however it was fruitless as well

Any help is appreciated!